# How can I take out values that are within +- 10 of each other

Tags: python, list

Please bear with me as I am quite new to python

An example of the list is this:

```
list = [2456116.494, 2456116.535, 2456116.57, 2456123.527, 2456166.634, 2456570.526, 2456595.515, 2457485.722, 2457497.93, 2457500.674, 2457566.874, 2457567.877]
```

I am trying to write a loop that will test the numbers, and if there are any numbers within +- 10 of each other, print only the first one.

So for example with these numbers, `2456116.494, 2456116.535, 2456116.57, 2456123.527` are all within 10 of each other. Therefore `2456116.494` will be printed as it is the first one. But this would be done to all the values within the list.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you

Comment: 1/ Do you want to throw away any within +/-10 of the *previous* number, or the *first* number in the set? In other words, should we throw away `19` *and* `22` in the sequence `10, 19, 22`?  2/ Do you want to throw away disparate ones such as the `13` in `10, 11, 12, 1000, 2000, 13`, or are you only interested in consecutive values in a connected set?

Comment: if the list is `[1, 10, 20]`, which one is your expected output `[1]`, `[1, 20]`, `[1]` or  `[10]`

Comment: is the list ordered? I assume you only consider "runs" of numbers, e.g. ```[1, 10, 20, 2]``` -> ```[1, 20, 2]```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = [2456116.494, 2456116.535, 2456116.57, 2456123.527, 2456166.634, 2456570.526, 2456595.515, 2457485.722, 2457497.93, 2457500.674, 2457566.874, 2457567.877]
first_range = 0
for n in list:
    if n - first_range <= 10:
        pass
    else:
        print(n)
        first_range = n
```